# How to remove this gray top border in JavaFX TextArea

Tags: javafx

I want a textarea that is completely with no borders and no background effects. Just plain white. I tried removing the border and background but there is this weird gray border that stays on top of the textarea.

[image]

Under the  "complaints" word there, that is a text area. I removed everything but still that gray line stays.

```
textArea.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #fff; -fx-border-color: #fff; -fx-border-width: 0; -fx-border-image-width: 0; -fx-background-image: null; -fx-region-background: null;-fx-border-insets: 0; -fx-background-size:0; -fx-border-image-insets:0;");
```

Comment: Two suggestions: 1. Post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so someone can recreate the problem for themselves. 2. Use [ScenicView](http://fxexperience.com/scenic-view/) to help you determine where the border is coming from.

Answer (score 4):

In JavaFX 8, like this:

```
.text-area {
    -fx-background-insets: 0;
    -fx-background-color: transparent, white, transparent, white;
}

.text-area .content {
    -fx-background-color: transparent, white, transparent, white;
}

.text-area:focused .content {
    -fx-background-color: transparent, white, transparent, white;
}

.text-area:focused {
    -fx-highlight-fill: #7ecfff;
}

.text-area .content {
    -fx-padding: 10px;
    -fx-text-fill: gray;
    -fx-highlight-fill: #7ecfff;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is probably a little late, but it might help someone out there!

I needed to use the JavaFx TextArea to display multiline text and I wanted the same look you were describing: no borders, just text.

Here is the styling I used:

```
textArea.setStyle("-fx-focus-color: transparent; -fx-text-box-border: transparent;");
```

Answer (score 2):

The actual styling applied to a `TextArea` can be found in the modena.css file. If you want to override any of the css properties you need to look for all the possible style classes and pseudo-classes where those appear, and then all the possible series of values (separated by commas) for a given property.

For the background color property, these are the default values:

```
.text-area {
    -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(to bottom, derive(-fx-text-box-border, -10%), -fx-text-box-border),
        derive(-fx-base,-1%);
}
.text-area .content {
    -fx-background-color:
        linear-gradient(from 0px 0px to 0px 4px, derive(-fx-control-inner-background, -8%), -fx-control-inner-background);
}
.text-area:focused .content {
    -fx-background-color: 
        -fx-control-inner-background,
        -fx-faint-focus-color,
        linear-gradient(from 0px 0px to 0px 5px, derive(-fx-control-inner-background, -9%), -fx-control-inner-background);
}
```

So if you want to have a complitely white area, with no borders, those values have to be overriden to:

```
.text-area{
    -fx-background-color: #fff, #fff;
}

.text-area .content {
    -fx-background-color: #fff;
}

.text-area:focused .content {
    -fx-background-color: #fff;
}
```